# How to automatically move trailing comments to the line above?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, uncrustify

I am looking for a tool, option, or regex to move trailing comments to above the line they describe. In other words I would like to turn this:

```
a = b; // Assign b to a
```

into this:

```
// Assign b to a
a = b;
```

I am currently using uncrustify to clean up a large code base, but it doesn't look like it has an option for this, nor could I find it in other tools, though I may have missed it somewhere. The code makes a lot of use of trailing comments, and for the most part they are randomly spaced and badly aligned.

Comment: I'm sure a regular expression would do it, did you try it already?

Comment: This question is off topic because: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow".

Comment: This is only for `//` comments? How about trailing `/* ..  */` comments?

Comment: be aware that your transformation can break compilation, e.g. in macro definitions

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex in Vim:

```
s:^\(.*\)\s\+\(//.*\):\2\r\1:
```